# react native link using expo?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, exponentjs

How can I use react-native link or How can I link a third party library manually in IOS and Android using exponent.

I was trying to link `react-native-image-crop-picker` but unable to use in exponent.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't. It states this very clearly [in the docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/introduction/faq#what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and):

> **But no native modules…**
>
> The most limiting thing about Expo is that you can’t add in your own native modules without detaching and using ExpoKit. Continue reading the next question for a full explanation.

If you want to use anything that requires `react-native link`, then you need to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/detach) your project and then develop it [with or without ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/expokit.html). You will lose certain features and integrations (off the top of my head, I think Push Notifications via Expo is one of them) when doing so, but that is the trade-off Expo provides as an all-in-one package. When detaching, you lose those features.

Comment: I came here wondering what to do for `@react-native-community/async-storage`. Good news is that it's supported by Expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/asyncstorage/

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, create a new fresh project with:

```
npx create-react-native-app
```

copy your files of components and your dependencies on the new generated project.

The best of both worlds, Expo and React-Native.

More information can be found in the docs:
https://github.com/expo/create-react-native-app#usage-with-expo-client-app

Comment: Isn't create-react-native-app just a deprecated version of expo though?

Comment: @Shidouuu I laughed so hard I cried... Very funny :)

Comment: @JohnyClash It wasn't a joke :/