# VictoryLine from Victory-Native not working in Expo

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

I'm posting this stack overflow questions with an answer, so that hopefully no one else spends ages as I have being perplexed that Victory-Native Charts are not displaying correctly.  It's so simple, yet so easy to miss.

When trying out the Victory-Native in an Expo app, I followed the installation instructions, and installed react-native-svg.  DO NOT do this, Expo includes react-native-svg by default, and for some reason installing it again in your node_modules causes any svg components to not work in the charts.

If you installed react-native-svg, just follow the instrutions in this SO thread:

[Can victory-native be used with expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468040/can-victory-native-be-used-with-expo)

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed react-native-svg, just follow the instrutions in this SO thread:

[Can victory-native be used with expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49468040/can-victory-native-be-used-with-expo)

Answer (score 0):

Using NativeBase as my UI framework, I am required to explicitly install react-native-svg as a dependency.

My solution is to use both "victory-native" and "victory". Since import statements cannot be dynamic/conditional in JS, this requires a bit of a workaround.

1. First workaround that I could not get working is to use aliasing in
   babel.config.js to switch "victory-native" to "victory" for web only. This means you "yarn add victory-native victory" such that you have both modules, and in the appropriate file you write "import {VictoryChart, VictoryBar } from "victory-native". The "victory-native" part will change to "native" on web. Again, I couldn't get this to work.
2. Second, slightly less elegant, workaround is to use [React Native's platform specific code solution](https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code). At the bottom of the link it explains the file.js and file.native.js solution. You can use that to expose the module dynamically

So for example I have two files: victory.ts and victory.native.ts (ts for typescript). Inside of victory.ts is the following:

```
import * as Victory from "victory";

export default Victory;
```

It's the same for victory.native.ts, except it references "victory-native" in the import statement.

In the component using Victory Charts I have the following...

```
import V from "@utils/victory"; // @utils is just an alias

// some other code...

function Chart() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <V.VictoryChart width={350} theme={V.VictoryTheme.material}>
        <V.VictoryBar data={data} x="quarter" y="earnings" />
      </V.VictoryChart>
    </View>
  );
}
```