# React Native Installing Packages

Tags: react-native, package

React-Native newbie here running into problems and wondering if I have missed a fundamental step in the installation of packages.

I have been trying to use the react-native-rsa-native package (https://github.com/amitaymolko/react-native-rsa-native)

However I am getting

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeRsaNative.RSA.generateKeys')
```

My test code is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { RSA, RSAKeychain } from 'react-native-rsa-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    RSA.generateKeys(4096) // set key size
      .then(keys => {
        console.log('4096 private:', keys.private) // the private key
        console.log('4096 public:', keys.public) // the public key
      });
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The steps followed were:

```
expo init rsatest --template blank@sdk-31 --yarn
cd rsatest
yarn add react-native-rsa-native
react-native link react-native-rsa-native
yarn start
```

The react-native-rsa-native package does appear in the node_modules directory however I feel I am missing something.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find solution to this problems? I am also facing same problem undefined (reading 'generateKeys')....

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may be relevant is componentWillMount is being deprecated.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html
React docs work as the foundation for react native docs.

Also with **componentWillMount()** if there is fetch call, with a promise, the promise will not return before component mount, the component will return empty at least once.

I suggest trying **componentDidMount()**

Hope this helps

Edited for spelling*

Comment: I've changed componentWillMount to componentDidMount and unfortunately the same error remains :(

Answer (score 0):

That library is not compatible with Expo. Check here why: [react native link using expo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44977693/react-native-link-using-expo)

So you might want to `expo eject`. Which I think is not an option either.

How about you try this one below instead?
https://github.com/z-hao-wang/react-native-rsa

Comment: That explains why it wasnt and will not work.
I had seen react-native-rsa but went for react-native-rsa-native as it provided sign and verify functionality which i will eventually need. I will keep searching.
Many thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the node modul and then 
npm install
react-native link
react-native run-android/ run-ios

maybe

this helpfull :
[how to delete installed library form react native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613790/how-to-delete-installed-library-form-react-native-project)